# HTML and JavaScript game development passing argument upon clicking sprite

Tags: javascript, html, game-development

I have created a game in html using javascript.  I am wanting to add an option at the very beginning of the game where you can click on either a boy or a girl sprite to start the game as that character respectively.  Right now I have the game starting when I run the following code:

```
<onload = "init()">
```

I have searched online quite a bit and have not been able to find what I am looking to do.  Basically before the init even initializes, I would like to have a screen (just a simple webpage) that has the boy sprite and girl sprite showing.  The final result would be that if the boy sprite is clicked then the game starts loading up all of the boy images and if the girl sprite is clicked then the game will start loading up all of the girl images.  The following is the code/pseudo of what I am trying to do but since html is a markup language I am not sure how I can implement this:

```
<body>

<p>


<IMG STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:250px; LEFT:100px; WIDTH:300px; HEIGHT:300px" SRC="images/boy.png"/>

<IMG STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:250px; LEFT:600px; WIDTH:300px; HEIGHT:300px" SRC="images/girl.png"/>


</p>

if (images/boy.png is clicked){
    var boy = "boy";
    <onload = "init(boy)"> // passes the argument of boy so images can be loaded accordingly
}

if (girlSprite is clicked){
    var girl = "girl";
    <onload = "init(girl)"> // passes the argument of girl so images can be loaded accordingly
}

</body>
```

Comment: I took a different approach and created a function for a different onload.  The function does everything I need but I am having a problem now where when switching to init(), the screen appears under the current one.  So I am running <onload = "checkPlayer()"> function, they click on the player, we then switch to init(), now the new screen is loaded up under the old one.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use a link element with sprite so as to catch the click event.

For example, In Case of Sprite Images:

```
<div id="example-boy-link">
  <a href="#" onclick="boyFunc();"/>
</div>

   #example-boy-link a { 
        display: inline-block;
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        background-image: url('yoursprite');
        background-position: -300px -100px;
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yeah, I actually already implemented it that way and it works, but it's not as efficient in the long run.  Thanks for your post!